# Change listing names?

Tags: listings

I use listings that way:

```
\begin{listing}
    \inputminted{python}{listings/models.py}
    \caption{Models}
    \label{listing:models}
\end{listing}
```

and I want to change Listing name to another but when I use this command `\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Another name}` it doesn't work. How to change it correctly?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The chances to get an answer, quick and to the point, considerably increase if you post a complete example, ready to run: A TeX document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, and a tiny sample Python file. Often, the correct answer depends on the document class and the packages loaded, so the sooner you include the info, the faster people can give advice.

Comment: As you are using the `minted` package check its manual section 4 (*Floating listings*). It describes several options depending on the other packages loaded (`caption`, `float`, `newfloat`, …)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the meaning of `\listingscaption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Whatever}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
\inputminted{latex}{\jobname.tex}
\caption{Models}
\label{listing:models}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

I used the same file for the listing, just for the sake of brevity.

[image]